# Failed - network error when downloading zip file made by Ionic.Zip.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, zip, ionic-zip

I try to download a zip file made by `Ionic.Zip.dll` from an asp.net c# web form application like this:

```
zip.AddEntry("filename", arraybyte);
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=SuppliersDocuments.zip");
zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
Response.Close();
```

But I get `Failed - network error` like this:

[image]

Error just occurs in **chrome** and it works properly in another browsers.
Error does not occur on my localhost and it happens only on the main server.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and this happens in Chrome. This issue is happening on Chrome v53 and later which is explained [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-admins/TREIV9vNp4A).

To overcome this issue I suggest you get the length of the file and use Content-Length in the header and pass the length of the file.

```
string fileName = string.Format("Download.zip");
Response.BufferOutput = false;  // for large files  
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
      zip.AddFile(path, "Download");
      Response.Clear();
      Response.Buffer = true;
      Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
      Response.AddHeader(name: "Content-Disposition", value: "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
      Int64 fileSizeInBytes = new FileInfo(path).Length;
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileSizeInBytes.ToString());                                    
      zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
      Response.Flush();
}
Response.Close();
```

Comment: IDK while you were down voted. Yours is the correct answer. This one line where I totaled all the files sizes. 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", longAllFileSizes.ToString());